# Want to overwrite functions written in woocommerce-functions.php file

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to modify/overwrite functions written in woocommerce-functions.php file but I don't want to modify   woocommerce-functions.php file. That is I want to achieve this in plug-in or in my theme.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is possible to override woocommerce functions, I did this recently and added all of my woocommerce extended functionality to my theme's functions.php file so that the woocommerce plugin files remained untouched and are safe to update.

This page gives an example of how you can remove their action and replace it with your own -
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/overriding-woocommerce_process_registration-in-child-theme-functionsphp

This page gives an example of extending upon their functions without removing their function, as well as using child themes - 
http://uploadwp.com/customizing-the-woocommerce-checkout-page/

Hope this helps :)

Comment: It seems working for me, but in my case I have to change hook name as

remove_action('template_redirect', 'woocommerce_save_password');
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'theme_woocommerce_save_password' );

Comment: The uploadwp link is currently dead. FYI.

Answer (score 4):

**WooCommerce** provides a templating system. It is possible to override woocommerce functions. great way to customize WooCommerce without modifying core files, is to use hooks -

If you use a hook to add or manipulate code, you can add your custom code to your theme functions.php file.

- **Using action hooks** -

To execute your own code, you hook in by using the action hook do_action(‘action_name’);.

See below for a great example on where to place your code:

```
add_action('action_name', 'your_function_name');

function your_function_name() 
{
// Your code
}
```

- **Using filter hooks**-

Filter hooks are called throughout are code using apply_filter(‘filter_name’, $variable);

To manipulate the passed variable, you can do something like the following:

```
add_filter('filter_name', 'your_function_name');

function your_function_name( $variable )
 {
// Your code
return $variable;
}
```

> Here you can get WooCommerce Action and Filter Hook - https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html

Answer (score 1):

If you have a child theme, you can copy the relevant file to your theme and rewrite the copy. The copy will be used in preference to the WooCommerce version.

Answer (score 0):

I was needed to add "Play" button for videos on mobile devices (by default this button is shown just on desktop).

I was needed to override the function in `wp-content/themes/gon/framework/theme_functions.php`:

```
function ts_template_single_product_video_button(){
    if( wp_is_mobile() ){
        return;
    }
    global $product;
    $video_url = get_post_meta($product->id, 'ts_prod_video_url', true);
    if( !empty($video_url) ){
        $ajax_url = admin_url('admin-ajax.php', is_ssl()?'https':'http').'?ajax=true&action=load_product_video&product_id='.$product->id;
        echo '<a class="ts-product-video-button" href="'.esc_url($ajax_url).'"></a>';
    }
}
```

I found [this instruction](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/introduction-to-hooks-actions-and-filters/) which states `If you use a hook to add or manipulate code, you can add your custom code to your theme’s functions.php file.`

I already had `wp-content/themes/gon-child/functions.php`, (ie the original **gon** theme had been copied to **gon-child**), so what I did was:

```
// Enable tour video on mobile devices
remove_action('ts_before_product_image', 'ts_template_single_product_video_button', 1);
add_action('ts_before_product_image', 'ts_template_single_product_video_button_w_mobile', 1);
function ts_template_single_product_video_button_w_mobile(){
    global $product;
    $video_url = get_post_meta($product->id, 'ts_prod_video_url', true);
    if( !empty($video_url) ){
        $ajax_url = admin_url('admin-ajax.php', is_ssl()?'https':'http').'?ajax=true&action=load_product_video&product_id='.$product->id;
        echo '<a class="ts-product-video-button" href="'.esc_url($ajax_url).'"></a>';
    }
}

?>
```