# Bypass validate_product_categories() in is_valid function core code for Class WC_Coupon

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, coupon

How to remove **`$this->validate_product_categories();`** in **`is_valid`** function in WooCommerce **`class-wc-coupon.php`** file without editing plugin?

Is there any hook for to do that in functions.php?

Here is the source code of **`class-wc-coupon.php`**:

```
/**
     * Check if a coupon is valid.
     *
     * @return boolean validity
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function is_valid() {
        try {
            $this->validate_exists();
            $this->validate_usage_limit();
            $this->validate_user_usage_limit();
            $this->validate_expiry_date();
            $this->validate_minimum_amount();
            $this->validate_maximum_amount();
            $this->validate_product_ids();
            $this->validate_product_categories();
            $this->validate_sale_items();
            $this->validate_excluded_items();
            $this->validate_cart_excluded_items();

            if ( ! apply_filters( 'woocommerce_coupon_is_valid', true, $this ) ) {
                throw new Exception( self::E_WC_COUPON_INVALID_FILTERED );
            }
        } catch ( Exception $e ) {
            echo $this->error_message = $this->get_coupon_error( $e->getMessage() );
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Why you want to remove it ? You can update plugin and check if there are any issues and can contact to support forum about the issue. Highly recommended.

Comment: Coming back to the solution of your question, in your *functions.php* i guess you need to overwrite this function. Something like this http://hookr.io/filters/woocommerce_coupon_is_valid/ not sure though.

Comment: Also check this once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21397325/want-to-overwrite-functions-written-in-woocommerce-functions-php-file

Comment: i want to remove product category validation in coupon

Comment: Did you check above links ?

Comment: yes but my hook is not working,

Answer (score 1):

**Updated**

This is a working tested code (without coupon restrictions for categories), so you will have to remove those category settings from your coupons. This code  will check and remove coupon if it doesn't match with the product Id added to cart *(as you have only 6 products in 2 categories).*

Here is that code:

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'custom_check_coupons', 10, 1 );
function custom_check_coupons( $cart_obj ) {
    $coupons_in_cart = $cart_obj->get_applied_coupons();

    if( ! empty($coupons_in_cart) ){

        // Set below your coupon slugs and your corresponding product IDs
        $coupon1 = 'couponslug1'; // Coupon group 1
        $product_ids_1 = array(56, 53, 50); // Product Ids for coupon group 1
        $coupon2 = 'couponslug2'; // Coupon group 2
        $product_ids_2 = array(24, 38, 44); // Product Ids for coupon group 2

        $coupon_match = false;

        foreach($cart_obj->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item_values) {
            $product_id = $cart_item_values['product_id'];
            if (in_array($product_id, $product_ids_1)){
                if(in_array($coupon1, $coupons_in_cart)){
                    $coupon_match = true;
                }
            } elseif (in_array($product_id, $product_ids_2)){
                if(in_array($coupon2, $coupons_in_cart)){
                    $coupon_match = true;
                }
            }
        }
        if( ! $coupon_match ){
            foreach($coupons_in_cart as $coupon){
                $cart_obj->remove_coupons($coupon);
                break;
            }
            // (optional) displaying a notice
            wc_add_notice( __( 'The coupon "'.$coupon.'" can’t be used and has been removed', 'woocoommerce' ), 'error' );
        }
    }
}
```

*The Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

---

You should try to use this custom function hooked in **`woocommerce_coupon_is_valid`** filter hook, to remove coupon validation for **`$this->validate_product_categories()`** case:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_coupon_is_valid', 'remove_product_cat_coupon_validation', 1, 2 );
function remove_product_cat_coupon_validation( $valid, $coupon ){
   if( ! $coupon->validate_product_categories() ) $valid = true;
}
```

*The Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This code should work.

Comment: not working for me i want to remove the throw new Exception from private function validate_product_categories()  if ( ! $valid_for_cart ) {
    throw new Exception( self::E_WC_COUPON_NOT_APPLICABLE );
   }